# How SVG works in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, svg, angular6, innerhtml

innerHTML not working for svg, the below mentioned code is not working for svg but it is work for `<i>` tag

```
<div *ngIf="link.portfolioCompanyLinkName.svgIcon !=null" [innerHtml]="link.portfolioCompanyLinkName.svgIcon"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if the svg is as string and you want to render it inside a div you have to use angular santizer

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

then in the constructor

```js
constructor(    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer    )
```

then in your template use

```js
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(yourSVG)
```